# Identify consecutive date by customer with same line in same company as a group and calculate the Duration and Total Spending in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to identify consecutive date (just 1 day gap between two consecutive records) by customer with same line in same company as a group and calculate the duration and total spending.

Here is the original data output I can generate with SQL query as below:

```
create table tbl
(
  Company   char,
  Line      char(2),
  Customer  varchar(5),
  StartDate date,
  Spending  decimal(10,2)
);

insert into tbl values 
('A',       's1',      'Tom',         '20210202',    10.00),
('A',       's1',      'Tom',         '20210201',    10.00),
('A',       's1',      'Tom',         '20210203',    10.00),
('A',       's2',      'Tom',         '20210204',    10.00),
('A',       's2',      'Tom',         '20210206',    10.00),
('B',       's1',      'Tom',         '20210201',    15.00),
('A',       's3',      'Tom',         '20210207',    10.00),
('A',       's3',      'Ken',         '20210207',    10.00),
('C',       's1',      'Tom',         '20210201',    20.00);
```

SQL code I use:

```
with
cte as
(
    select *, 
           g = case when Line = lag(Line) over (partition by Company, Customer 
                                                     order by StartDate)
                    then 0
                    else 1
                    end
    from   tbl
),
cte2 as
(
    select *, grp = sum(g) over (partition by Company, Customer 
                                     order by StartDate)
    from   cte
)
select Company, Line, Customer,
      StartDate = min(StartDate),
       EndDate = max(StartDate),
       Duration = datediff(day, min(StartDate), max(StartDate)) + 1,
       TotalSpending = sum(spending)
from   cte2
group by Company, Customer, Line, grp
order by Company, Customer, grp
```

Here is the output I expect:

```
Company Line    Customer    StartDate   EndDate    Duration TotalSpending
A       s1      Tom         2021-02-01  2021-02-03  3   30.00
A       s2      Tom         2021-02-04  2021-02-04  1   10.00
A       s2      Tom         2021-02-06  2021-02-06  1   10.00
A       s3      Tom         2021-02-07  2021-02-07  1   10.00
B       s1      Tom         2021-02-01  2021-02-01  1   15.00
C       s1      Tom         2021-02-01  2021-02-01  1   20.00
A       s3      Ken         2021-02-07  2021-02-07  1   10.00
```

The criteria is:

1. "EndDate" is the last consecutive startDate (just 1 day gap/interval between two consecutive records) in a group which has same line and same company given a customer.
2. Duration = (Enddate - startdate)+1
3. TotalSpending is the sum of a group with same line and same company given a customer and consecutive startdate.
4. If the same customer had multiple entries for the same date and same company, it's due to the duplicates which should be removed.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What does this have to do with PowerBI? I haven't removed the tag, in case it does have some relation, but I can't see what. Can you elaborate what you are asking about is about PowerBI Desktop? Are you looking to do the transformation in that application?

Comment: `=10+20=26` ? I believe that should be `30`

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that.

Comment: Pleae edit your question to include any corrections.

Comment: In one comment you posted data where the same customer had multiple entries for the same date. Is that possible or not? If possible, precisely what behaviour is required? What if they not for the same Line?

Comment: Thanks Mat. If the same customer had multiple entries for the same date and same company, it's due to the duplicates which should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to group by Customer with same line as a group and then calculate the Duration and Total Spending.

First cte use [lead()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to find when there is a change in `Line`.

Second cte calculate a cumulative `sum()` to form the `group`

Final query just do a `GROUP BY` and calculate the required `Duration` & `Total Spending`

```
with
cte as
(
    select *, 
           g = case when Line = lead(Line) over (partition by Company, Customer 
                                                     order by StartDate)
                    then 1
                    else 0
                    end
    from   tbl
),
cte2 as
(
    select *, grp = sum(g) over (partition by Company, Customer 
                                     order by StartDate)
    from   cte
)
select Company, Line, Customer,
       StartDate = min(StartDate),
       EndDate   = max(StartDate),
       Duration  = datediff(day, min(StartDate), max(StartDate)) + 1,
       TotalSpending = sum(Spending)
from   cte2
group by Company, Line, Customer, grp
order by Company, Line, Customer
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=49c619e52a165b0de6650288ada5209e)

Comment: I tried it. Looks some cases work but some not.  Here is the case that doesn't work.  Can you please take it look?  Thanks. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7612fc274ad54cb3a7b9eb81a1198bbe

Comment: Should be `CASE WHEN line = LAG(line) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`... If the `line` is the same as the preceding row, don't increment the group identifier.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=324de6ad8e36a9349e76f478374a02f5

Comment: @ben Please update your question with all the requirements, and include sample data that covers every need you have. At present (with the correction) this does what you asked for, using the sample data you provided.